# Adding a new ui-router state at the top of ionic tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue where I would like to add a new tab button at the top of my app but also have three tabs at the bottom of my app.  So 4 states.  3 at the bottom and 1 at the top and all going to separate views.  I am having trouble getting the top one to work.

I do not know where to put the `<ion-nav-vew>`.  I currently have all three views under ion-tabs but the view that is supposed to go at the top can't go in an ion-tab or it will end up on the bottom.  I have made a button that changes to that state in my index.html file but I do not know where to put my `<ion-nav-view>`

I have created a plunker to explain my problem better.  I have made notes in tabs.html to make it more clear.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PTS9Jt?p=preview

Note: The plunker seems to only work for IE after you click on "Show all content"

Thanks.

Comment: Aint this more a matter of CSS than anything else? Your ion-nav-view will be in the tabs.html file, but just in a different position.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different position'?  I still want the view to take over the entire screen.  If mean a different position in the code, thats the problem; I don't know where to put it.